# HMAC-MD5 with CryptoApi

Tags: c, windows, winapi, cryptoapi

I have adopted the [SHA1 HMAC example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from Microsoft's website and modified it according to this [stack-overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103961/to-implement-hmac-md5-crypto-algorithm-in-an-win32-application) and some other suggestions on the Internet, however I am unable to produce correct values.

Basically I just replaced SHA1 with MD5 CALG_SHA1 -> CALG_MD5.

Does anyone have a working example?

Does it matter what algo is used for CryptDeriveKey() for the password (RC2 or RC4)?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
Found working code [here](http://masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=1612.0)

Comment: What are the correct values? From where did you got them?

Comment: Can you provide a relevant code snippet along with your input and your output and point out the error and the output that you expect?

Comment: Unfortunately my companies DLP won't let me post source code. Basically I took the SHA1 example and replaced CALG_SHA1 with CALG_MD5. I am comparing the values to output from Python's hmac calculation and some sample values from Wikipedia article about HMAC MD5

Answer (score 1):

Your values are different from examples cause you use different keys:
Example values can be obtained using Linux `openssl dgst -md5 -hmac key < input` command. This command uses key *as is* if its length smaller than MD5 hash block length (64 bytes) otherwise its uses MD5(key) as key and not key derived using CryptDeriveKey(RC4, MD5(key)) like in your implementation.